# How to drop all rows where the first column contains a specific character without referencing column name?

Tags: python, pandas

With a data frame, I want to drop all rows where the first columns contains the string or substring 'XYZ'. I know this works:

```
df[~df.NameOfColumn.str.contains("XYZ")]
```

However, I do not want to use the name of the first column. (This is because I have lots of dataframes and the names of their first column is different). Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select first column by position `0`, here `:` means select all rows:

```
df[~df.iloc[:, 0].str.contains("XYZ")]
```